# Probability: Yellow M&M

Tags: probability-theory

I am not sure if I did this problem correctly. I am specifically confused about the part stating, "uniformly distributed between $5$ and $15$ inclusive."

In a package of M&Ms, $Y$, the number of yellow M&Ms in uniformly distributed between $5$ and $15$ inclusive. What is the probability that $Y \leq 10$ and that $Y$ is even?

I am assuming that the number of Yellow M&Ms range between $5$ and $15$ in a package.

$P = P[6] + P[8] + P[10] = 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 = 3/10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the random variable for the number of yellow M$\&$Ms. 
Your probability mass function (pmf) is 
$$
P(Y=x) = p(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{11} &\mbox{ if } x = 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, \\ 
\: 0   &\mbox{ otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
$$
Then 
\begin{align*}
P(Y\leq 10 \mbox{ and }Y \mbox{ is even}) &= P(Y=6)+ P(Y=8)+ P(Y=10) \\ 
&= p(6) + p(8) + p(10)  \\
&=\frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{11} +\frac{1}{11}  \\ 
&= \frac{3}{11}. 
\end{align*}